# Ruby can not find the module (LoadError) under Windows

Tags: ruby, windows, firebird

I tried to connect to the database using Ruby (under Windows).
For that:

- install Ruby in C:\Ruby193
- install devkit (c:\ruby193\devkit). Run "ruby dk.rb init", "ruby dk.rb install"
- downloaded rubygems (1.8.25). Executed ruby setup.rb
- and:  gem install rubyfb (adapter Ruby for Firebird)

After that I wrote short rb-script:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rubyfb'
include Rubyfb

db = Database.new('test.gdb')
```

And got error:

> C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': 126: Can't find module   - C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rubyfb-0.6.7/lib/rubyfb_lib.so (LoadError)

This is the file exists, but Ruby can not find it. 
All my attempts to rectify the situation failed.

I installed another adapter, but the situation repeated - Ruby can not find another file.

Please advise.

Comment: The error seems to indicate that it is trying to load a linux library (`.so`). Are you sure this is actually supported on Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same problem. All I had to do was copying `C:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_2_5\bin\fbclient.dll` to `C:\Ruby\bin`.